# Convert a stringified array back to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I use hstore with Postgres 9.2 and Rails 3.2 to store my object like this:

```
class User
  user_hstore = {:user_id =>"123", :user_courses => [1,2,3]}
end
```

Now, when I retrieve user_courses, I get a string like this:
`'[1, 2, 3]'`

How do I convert this string to Rails array? Better yet, is there a way to store an array within a hstore object so that Rails will automatically retrieve it as array type?

Comment: Despite my earlier answer, it's Postgres offers no support for anything beyond string values. I suspect given the overlap between `serialize` and hstore functionality, there isn't a readymade solution for this.

Comment: The team is working on improving this for PostgreSQL 9.4, which will hopefully have a fully indexable, nestable, json-compatible replacement for hstore. See http://lwn.net/Articles/553256 (currently subscriber only, will be readable to everyone next week sometime).

Comment: Hi Craig: thanks for the info. Silly question: Rails needs to support this feature too before we can use it, correct?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to wait for Rails (or a plugin) to properly support the new hstore stuff. OTOH, there's also a JSON data type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, there is a gem for that: [store_complex](https://github.com/moonfly/store_complex). Still under development.

Answer (score 11):

```Ruby
JSON.parse "[\"1018\", \"1037\", \"1045\", \"1042\"]"
#=> ["1018", " 1037", " 1045", " 1042"]
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not just use `eval`?

```Ruby
eval('[1, 2, 3]')
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Obviously, don't do this on arbitrary or user inputted data, but on an array of integers as you've displayed, it's perfectly safe.

Answer (score 2):

To convert it to an array:

```
user_courses.gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '').split(",")
```

To make retrieval simpler, you can store it as a string by doing

```
user_hstore = {:user_id =>"123", :user_courses => '1,2,3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw another hat into the ring, this accomplishes the same as Vimsha's answer but is a little more short and sweet you could do:

```
"[1,2,3,4]"[1..-2].split(",")
```

which in your case could be:

```
user_courses[1..-2].split(",")
```

Edit:
  If speed is a concern I did a quick benchmark which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jasontruluck/5762470). Doing only a few items is not a very big difference but 10,000 items + you can start seeing a difference. This is at 100,000 items:

```
  # "[1,2,3,4]"[1..-2].split(",")
  0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.114739)

  # "[1,2,3,4]".gsub("[", "").gsub("", "]").split(",")
  1.080000   0.000000   1.080000 (  1.081227)
```